# Troubleshoot a program crash with Windows Application Compatibility Tool

Tags: windows-vista, compatibility

I'm trying to troubleshoot why exactly my game, Monopoly Tycoon, is crashing. Reports around the internet say that disabling music will fix it, but I don't want to do that, I'd like to enjoy my music in game. Surely there must be some way to fix this, since the game works fine on Windows XP.

I've tried the generic path of setting compatibility settings in the properties of the application, but no luck. I've now gotten the Windows ACT installed and running, although I don't know how to pinpoint what exactly is crashing my program. The preset fix for my game does not work, either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: "the game works fine on Windows XP" - Does [turning off UAC in Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off) fix the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid not, the game still crashes.